# What happened to the question "is the mvc software architecture used only in web development"

Tags: support, moderation

I had just finished typing a great answer, and It wouldn't let me post?

Comment: [per screen shot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/q9D7q.png), question has been deleted 6 minutes after being asked, and you managed to think through and type a "great answer" _that_ quickly?

Comment: @gnat As long as the page was opened in those 6 minutes, he could have spent days on it as long as he didn't close the browser/refresh the page.

Comment: @Izkata Nope, there's an ajax-y (websocket-y?) notification upon closure/deletion. That said, it's not impossible to write a great answer in 6 minutes or less.

Comment: @YannisRizos I've done it myself, you aren't notified until you submit your answer.  (Although if it's entirely through websockets, those don't always work - for example, at work that port is blocked)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(10k link - https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/219691/is-the-mvc-software-architecture-used-only-in-web-development )

It was deleted by the author of the question - likely when they realized it wasn't going to garner a positive response in its current form.

[image: screen shot]

Comment: At the time i started my answer it had no score, no answer, and was not marked duplicate. This seems to happen to every question I try to answer here.

Comment: btw: it happened again http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/219692/non-animalian-non-vehicular-oop-examples

Comment: The OP deleted the question 1 minute after I posted my comment asking for clarification.  It wasn't through any intervention by anyone else. Your best approach would be to look at ones that show that they've put some thought into asking the question.

Comment: And as to it happening again, another screen shot - http://i.stack.imgur.com/Dcnre.png (again, the OP deleted the question)

Comment: I notice how quickly questions get down voted here, even my question which last I checked has a score of 9 had a -2 before it got answered.

Comment: The ratio of people voting on questions to the rate of new questions is rather high (compared to other SE sites). The history of the site has had some tumultuous times and there are people (you'll note my vote) who try to give prompt feedback on questions (that are sometimes down votes) to help people realize they need to work on improving their question (or answer) before we get poor answers on it and it becomes a more difficult thing to fix.  Meta and [chat] are both ways to work on a question before "throwing it to the wolves".

Comment: both meta and chat require reputation . . . I'm just glad that pse was not my first se site.

Comment: On P.SE, we strive for thorough and complete answers.  Good answers can take a quarter of an hour or longer to think about and properly craft.  Similarly, we appreciate when the person asking the question has put some thought or research into it (rather than a 10 second "I'm wondering about..."). There are sites with even more strict requirements ( http://mathoverflow.net/ and http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/ being two that I can think of off the top of my head and http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/ doesn't allow home network questions - enterprise only)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11717/discussion-between-hildred-and-michaelt)

Comment: @hildred: Before answering your next question, read http://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic, and try to get a feel for what we consider good questions here.  Hint:  questions asking us to compile a list of things, or asking for product recommendations, are not what we consider good questions.  Answering such questions decreases your chance of a good outcome.

Comment: @RobertHarvey per your link both questions were on topic.

Comment: The MVC one was a duplicate.  What was the other one?

Comment: @RobertHarvey the other was also likely a duplicate (its in the comment that din't show in the cut) of [What would be the best real example to explain the usefulness of Inheritance ?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/108148/) (which was a closed question as not-constructive).

Answer (score 0):

*10k+ only link:*  [This is the question you're asking about](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/219691/is-the-mvc-software-architecture-used-only-in-web-development)

At the time of deletion, it had a suggested duplicate question in the comments.

The owner of the question chose to delete it.